# LaTeX Source Code Listing

Tags: listings

I want a code listing, but the code I'm listing is LaTeX.  When I simply use:

```
\usepackage{listings}
...
\begin{lstlisting}
...LaTeX document goes here...
\end{lstlisting}
```

The listing looks like this:

[image: screenshot of listing generated by above code]

I want it to look a little more professional than this.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: a trivial approach is to use the `verbatim` package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `\lstset` to customize your listings; select the specific language and a nice monospaced font; for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

If you are typsetting LaTeX code and want to show the output, I would recommend [the `showexpl` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) as it shows the code and the output in one step:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstdefinestyle{myLatexStyle}{
    language=TeX,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={align,begin},
    pos=l
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Here is a basic example:
\begin{LTXexample}[style=myLatexStyle,width=0.60\linewidth]
  \title{Sample Document}
  \author{John Smith}
  \date{\today}
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
    Hello World!
  % This is a comment.
  \end{document}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

---

It was suggested in the comments that the `LTXexample` environment can not typeset a complete LaTeX input file with `\documentclass` and `\usepackage`.  This does not appear to be the case as these two basic examples illustrate:

[image]

Since the `LTXexample` environment is designed to show the effect of code snippets, multi-page documents do not not show so well.

### Notes:

- One restriction I have found is that the packages must be included in the main file. So note that to show the use of the `\lipsum` package in the example below, it necessitated updating the preamble to include that.
- Even though the example here shows a different document class, it appears that `\documentclass` is ignored which can be shown by using `\documentclass{foobar}` which still produces output.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstdefinestyle{myLatexStyle}{
    language=TeX,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={align,begin},
    pos=l
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Here is a basic example:
\begin{LTXexample}[style=myLatexStyle,width=0.60\linewidth]
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{listings}

  \begin{document}
    Hello world!
  \end{document}
\end{LTXexample}

\noindent
Here is an example of using the \texttt{lipsum} package:
\begin{LTXexample}[style=myLatexStyle,width=0.60\linewidth]
  \documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{document}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Forgiver: Full LaTeX files do appear to work fine, at least when the output produced is one page.  Do you have an example that does not work?

Comment: Yes I mentioned in the **Notes** section that the package must be loaded in the main file.

Comment: @Forgiver: Different `\documentclass` still produces output (see updated images). However, the effect of changing `\documentclass` will not be apparent.

Comment: @Forgiver: Yes, like I said the `\documentclass` and `\usepacakge` are ignored. So if you want to show something specific to a class that you are not using you need to define those macros beforehand.

Answer (score 14):

It is my own favorite settings:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    %alsolanguage={PGF/TikZ},
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\sf,
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
    commentstyle=\color{cyan},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello World!
% This is a comment.
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: language={PGF/TikZ} does not work. Any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 12):

Same as Gonzalo's answer but with some spice added...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\lstset{%
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX},   numbersep=5mm, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, % number style
breaklines=true,frame=single,framexleftmargin=8mm, xleftmargin=8mm,
prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
backgroundcolor=\color{green!5},frameround=fttt,escapeinside=??,
rulecolor=\color{red},
morekeywords={% Give key words here                                         % keywords
    maketitle},
keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},                    % keywords
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},    % comments
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941}  % strings
%columns=fullflexible   
}%

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello World!
% This is a comment.
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]