# Is there any good books/documents that describe LaTeX usage in Computer Science?

Tags: books

Till now I know that using LaTeX CS students can draw UML diagram easily with gorgeous look. I personally use LaTeX to make UML for my Software Design Pattern Lab.

LaTeX also supports for following things-

1.topological sort([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394371/need-help-creating-a-topological-sort-diagram))
2.any graph
3.DFA & NFA([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/which-package-can-be-used-to-draw-automata))
4.source code listings([example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books), [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57121/latex-source-code-listing), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175105/writing-code-in-latex-document))

Now, I need a book/document that describe all topics for those a CS student can use LaTeX.

Comment: "writing good looking essays" is a valid topic for CS and any other discipline. And, to me, it's good enough to justify using LaTeX.

Comment: @Ignasi add it in the question with example if you sure that this match with the topic I asked.

Comment: I mean that this is the main topic for using LaTeX, all your proposed benefits are a plus.

Comment: @Ignasi -- the question is not whether or why cs students should use latex, but whether there are any books on how to use latex directed particularly at the cs community.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are right.

Comment: Every community has its own needs and remedies... You might find [Latex for Logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/), [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237100/34551), [that document](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ulrikb/80-413-713/documents/LaTeX_howto.pdf) and [this page](http://cat.boffosocko.com/2015/05/commutative-diagrams-in-latex/) of interest if you're looking for resources for logic and category theory. But I doubt you'll ever find a textbook about how Latex can deal with those topics.

Answer (score 5):

[Typesetting figures for computer science](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-2/tb110mertz.pdf) by Andrew Mertz, William Slough and Nancy Van Cleave from Department of Mathematics and Computer Science, Eastern Illinois University.

This article covers -

**.** Source code listings
**.** Drawing logic circuits
**.** Drawing stacks and stack frames
**.** Displaying fields of bit in machine instruction
**.** Drawing automata
**.** Drawing tree
**.** Grammars and parse trees
**.** Combinatorial graphs